# What would you like to see as our challenge week topics?

Tags: discussion, challenge-week

It's time to propose the topics for our Challenge Week!

Some notes:

1. Propose one topic per answer (make it CW by checking the checkbox under your answer);

   Write them like
   `## Topic <br><br>

   "description"`.
2. No maximum of proposals, but don't just propose tons of stuff. Propose things that could stimulate questions and answers.
3. Vote other proposals **up** if you like them, and **down** if you don't.
4. Include a short description or notes, otherwise the system won't let you post your answer.

For each Challenge Week, we'll take the most voted proposal (excluding the already asked ones), so keep proposing! Don't wait for others to propose!

Any questions? Use the comments below. :)

Comment: Are these topics supposed to be so general? Maybe I don't understand how challenge week works.

Comment: @MarkBeadles What do you mean? They can be anything related to Linguistics and "broad enough" so they have many "sides" and it doesn't limit the amount of questions... If you have questions, comment here or go to the chat! :)

Comment: Here's some "meta suggestions": Any *good* tags with low numbers of questions. Any linguistics fields that don't even have a tag yet. Any topics for which you feel we don't yet have good q/a's or which seem unclear of fuzzy or inconclusive. Topics which you don't know much about because they're outside your field but which you find fascinating.

Comment: @hippietrail Not bad ideas! Propose them so we can vote on! Propose the 2 or 3 you feel as most successful, but you can post more too if you wish.

Comment: @Alenanno: Well they're meta suggestions - suggestions for how to think of topics to suggest (-:

Comment: @hippietrail Well, they're still ideas, consider posting them, since they are your ideas! :) If you don't post them, people won't be able to vote on them.

Answer (score 4):

### Historical linguistics

The study of how languages evolve over the centuries usually interests not only professional linguists, but also classicists, literary critics, as well as other users just interested in languages in general. Historical linguistics will probably make for a great challenge!

Answer (score 3):

### Computational Linguistics

An interdisciplinary field dealing with the statistical or rule-based modeling of natural language from a computational perspective.

Answer (score 3):

### Methodology

Topics concerning how linguistic arguments are made, and what is permitted as evidence in supporting a linguistic argument. Questions ideally highlight debates in methodology and different methodological frameworks in different subfields.

Answer (score 2):

### Syntax

The rules and the study of rules that study the construction of sentences in a given language.

Answer (score 2):

### Second language(s) acquisition

Questions regarding the mechanisms for the acquisition of second languages.

Answer (score 1):

### Phonology

The branch of linguistics which investigates the ways in which sounds are used systematically in different languages to form words and utterances.

Answer (score 1):

### Pragmatics

A branch of linguistics which studies the ways in which context contributes to meaning.