# Challenge Weeks Discussion - [#3] Methodology

Tags: discussion, challenge-week

> **(!) NOTE**: Information may vary until the start of the Challenge. So keep checking!
>
> The Challenge Weeks are currently on hold. :)

**Premise**: This Meta question will be the one we will use for this Challenge Week but also for the future ones. The title will change after the hyphen, showing the Challenge's number (in order of time) and the topic for the current week, or for the upcoming one.

- If you want to read about the previous weeks, check the **[Challenge Wiki Database](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/251/111)**.
- If you want to propose a topic, then check **[the appropriate meta discussion](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/230/111)**!

---

We will use this topic to advertise it, and in the meantime we decide who gets selected. Basically we decide some requirements, if during the week you fulfil these requirements, you'll get included in a draw that will decide the winner.

> **For this third challenge, I lowered the limit to 50 views, so it's easier to participate! Just share your question to increase that by thousands!**

### Information

1. **What's the topic?**

   > Methodology
2. **When will it be?**

   > 12 March 00.00 UTC - 18 March 23.59 UTC, 2012
   >
   > (**Note**: only questions in such dates will be considered.)
3. **How do I participate?**

   > You must ask questions about Methodology and tag them [methodology](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/methodology) (If you start writing it or if you write something that belongs to the tag name spelling, the system will propose it to you).
   >
   > *Usual rules apply*: use the appropriate tags, no polls, no list questions, etc.
4. **How do I get selected?**

   > The parameter we have thought is the **Page views**! The minimum limit is **50**. The better the question, the easier it is to gain attention, but there are ways to improve this! How? **Sharing!**
   >
   > The easiest way is using the buttons on the left, after the question has been asked:
   >
   > [image]
   >
   > Alternatively, you can just share the question address wherever you want it to be seen... and clicked. :)
5. **How is the winner selected?**

   > When the week ends and we get — *for example* — 6 candidates, we pass their names to the CHAOS/SE team, and they will take a draw. After that the winner is selected.
6. **Wait, a draw? So it's random?**

   > Well... Yes. But your work is still important! Basically (data by the end of the Challenge):
   >
   > - 1 Question with 50 views is 1 lot in the draw.
   > - Every +50 is a +1 lot in the draw, so 150 views = 3 lots
   > - Every additional question with 50 views is 1 lot. So 3 questions with 50 views each = 3 lots.
   >
   > Therefore, the **more questions you ask** and the **more you share** ➝ the **more chances you'll have to win**!
7. **What do I win?**

   > The **GLORY** of being among the first winners of the Linguistics SE Challenge Week series! :P

### Good luck!

Comment: Why have a special tag for the challenge? Couldn't it be simply [tag:historical-linguistics]?

Comment: @OtavioMacedo You're right.

Comment: ### #1 Challenge Week questions: Historical Linguistics
<br> 1. ... 2. ...

Comment: I modified the time in order to be unambiguous. Hope it's OK.

Comment: @LouisRhys No problem. :D

Comment: Given that we've just concluded our third challenge and no winner has been announced so far, I propose changing the rules for the next one: whatever the question that has received the highest number of views wins (that is, no draw). That way, the competition becomes more straightforward and we don't need to bother CHAOS.

Comment: @OtavioMacedo Uhm. I'll ask them if that can work. Asking for advice won't harm. :D