# Challenge Weeks Database

Tags: discussion, challenge-week

This is the Meta question we use to group all the previous Weeks!

**Each answer** is a Challenge Week, where you can see the **questions asked** for that Challenge, the **topic** and of course, the **winner**

If you want to see what is the current/next Challenge Week, check the **[Challenge Wiki Discussion](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/247/111)**.

### Index

- [#1 - Historical Linguistics](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/259/111)
- [#2 - Syntax](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/291/111)
- [#3 - Methodology](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/310/22)

Comment: I am considering changing my user name to [yet to be decided] ;)

Comment: @MarkBeadles Ahahah sorry. Later today I'll annoy some CHAOS member. :D

Answer (score 3):

**Challenge Week #1**

*13 February 2012 - 20 February 2012*

The Week's topic was **Historical Linguistics** and our glorious winner was **[yet to be decided]**!

Questions:

- (120) [Where did Spanish get its /x/? Arabic influence?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1443/111)
- (71) [Is the Dené–Yeniseian hypothesis widely accepted, and has it led to further research?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1434/111)
- (52) [Is it possible to determine genetic relations without external historical data?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1430/111)
- (136) [When and how did French become a non-null-subject language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1408/111)
- (74) [How do linguists tell areal features and genetic relations apart?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/1410/111)

Comment: So when do we get to learn the winner? This is more exciting than the Academy Awards!

Comment: @MarkBeadles Ahah I'm glad you're interested! There is an obstacle: we decided the limit to be 100, but only two would be eligible that way, so *maybe*, for this time only we might lower it to 50 and make all of the questions participate. I'll let you know if there are news. :)

Comment: A promise is a promise, @Alenanno, I guess we'll have to draw between these two.

Comment: I agree, just follow the rules as stated at the time the challenge made.

Answer (score 0):

**Challenge Week #2**

*27 February, 2012 - 4 March, 2012*

The Week's topic was **Syntax** and our glorious winner was **[yet to be decided]**!

Questions:

- (29) [Does Chinese have proper nouns and are they distinguished morphosyntactically or only lexically and or semantically?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1558/does-chinese-have-proper-nouns-and-are-they-distinguished-morphosyntactically-or)
- (99) [Why the infinitive in Portuguese "Cartago tem que ser destruída"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1522/why-the-infinitive-in-portuguese-cartago-tem-que-ser-destruida)
- (20) [Focus-marking in different varieties of Spanish](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1544/focus-marking-in-different-varieties-of-spanish)
- (22) [how to transform complex/compound sentences to simple sentences?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1546/how-to-transform-complex-compound-sentences-to-simple-sentences)
- (203) [Does Pirahã syntax contradict the principles of Universal Grammar?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1515/does-piraha-syntax-contradict-the-principles-of-universal-grammar)
- (84) [In which varieties of English is it common to front predicates as in "Bought a nice house, he did."?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1494/in-which-varieties-of-english-is-it-common-to-front-predicates-as-in-bought-a-n)
- (41) [How common is it for languages to use second person pronouns as indefinite pronouns in certain contexts?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1527/how-common-is-it-for-languages-to-use-second-person-pronouns-as-indefinite-prono)

Comment: I think for this one, too, the rules are the rules - even if only one qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

**Challenge Week #3**

*12 March, 2012 - 18 March, 2012*

The Week's topic was **Methodology** and our glorious winner was **[yet to be decided]**!

Questions:

- (121) [How does a linguist determine whether a pattern is grammatical in a language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/how-does-a-linguist-determine-whether-a-pattern-is-grammatical-in-a-language)
- (44) [Are there alternatives to the comparative method in historical linguistics?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/are-there-alternatives-to-the-comparative-method-in-historical-linguistics)

Comment: Oh... This one was not so successful. I suppose the topic didn't get a lot of attention. Maybe it was too hard?